# MD-Join Abbreviation / Meaning

Tags: olap, relational-algebra

I'm reading some data warehouse tutorials, and I bumped into "MD-Join". While I do understand its functionality, I have two other questions about it

- What does "MD" stay for ?
- Is it implemented by current RDBMS or where and how in reality it is used ?

Comment: probably, Multi-dimensional.

Comment: I also came up with this suggestion later on.